# Downloading the file from the cloud by entering the name of the file through my graphical interface

Tags: python, encryption, nextcloud, node-crypto, identification

My project is to develop a Python application that allows users to encrypt their client-side data and store it securely on my university's NextCloud collaboration system via WebDAV.

I have a problem in the decryption part, I want the file to be downloaded from the cloud but when I enter the name of the file for it to search and download, it doesn't find that file on the cloud, so I have to do this step manually every time, I enter the NextCloud I download the file to my desktop then decrypt it.

What can I do so that the file to be decrypted can be downloaded from the cloud automatically, just by entering the name of the file through my graphical interface?

```
# Function for selecting a file to decrypt from the cloud
def select_decryption_file():
    # Request user credentials to access the cloud
    username = simpledialog.askstring("Authentification", "User Name :", parent=window)
    password = simpledialog.askstring("Authentification", "Pass Word :", parent=window, show='*')

    # Check user identification details
    if username == "****" and password == "*****":
        file_list = client.list()
        if file_list:
            selected_file = simpledialog.askstring("Select a file to decrypt", "File name :", parent=window)
            found_file = False
            for file_info in file_list:
                file_name = file_info['path'].split('/')[-1]
                if file_name == selected_file:
                    found_file = True
                    break
            if found_file:
                local_file_path = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), selected_file)
                client.download_sync(remote_path=selected_file, local_path=local_file_path)
                encryption_key = get_key(selected_file)
                if encryption_key:
                    decrypt_file(local_file_path, encryption_key)
                else:
                    messagebox.showerror("Encryption key not found", "No encryption key is associated with this file.")
                os.remove(local_file_path)  # Delete the downloaded file after decryption
            else:
                messagebox.showerror("File not found", "The selected file does not exist on the cloud.")
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("No file", "There are no files on the cloud.")
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("Authentication error", "Incorrect user name or password.")
```